# Issue with Azure B2C Reset Password user flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I have recently developed an ASP.net MVC web application which uses Azure B2C to authenticate users.

I have been asked to enable the Reset Password User flow to enable users to reset via self-service.

I created the user flow within the portal (using the correct identity provider and setting Reset password using email address) and added the code from the microsoft example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) however every time I click reset password, it just directs me back to the login screen and it never reaches the reset password page.

When I click the forgot password link the method below is called , it steps through the code fine, but then loads the login page.

**Reset Password code**

```
public void ResetPassword(string redirectUrl)
    {
        // Let the middleware know you are trying to use the reset password policy (see OnRedirectToIdentityProvider in Startup.Auth.cs)
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Startup.PasswordResetPolicyId);

        // Set the page to redirect to after changing passwords
        var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" };
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);

        return;
    }
```

The policy ID is correct in both azure and in the code as I step through and the values are all pulling through correctly (see below):

**Policy ID string (as used above)**

```
public static string PasswordResetPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId"];
```

**In Web.config where the policy is defined**

```
<add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="B2C_1_UserApp_ResetPassword" />
```

I have provided all the code samples I have added for the reset function to work, the rest of the code is all included in the Microsoft Web App example.

Has anyone else experienced something similar? As I said previously, when you click the forgot password link it does exactly as it should and goes to the correct controller/method, but then goes back to the login screen.

Comment: So you mean its loading the sign in/up policy after you click forgot password, and you have traced the code to be going via `public void ResetPassword(string redirectUrl)` in the `accountController`? What happens when you use the "Run Now" option in the Portal and launch `B2C_1_UserApp_ResetPassword` - what do you see?

Comment: Yes, it loads the sign in policy when I click forgot password. If I "Run Now" straight from the Azure Portal it takes me to B2C_1_UserApp_ResetPassword

Comment: @JasSuri I've figured out the issue, was missing app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(PasswordResetPolicyId)); from configureAuth

Answer (score 1):

Searching through my code, I found that the line

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(PasswordResetPolicyId));
```

was missing from ConfigureAuth. Once added this has fixed the issue.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {

                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()

            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));
            /////////////////
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(PasswordResetPolicyId));
        }
```